# Duplicates in QSet

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, set, duplicates

For a class X and a QSet< X* >, how is it possible to make sure that the QSet doesn't contain duplicate elements?
The unique property in each object of type X is a QString that can be fetched using getName().

I've implemented the qHash(X*) function, the operator==(), operator<() and operator>(), but the QSet still accepts duplicate elements, i.e., those with the same Name.

Could someone help me out in making this work?

---

Ok. Here's what I'm trying to do.
I have a class Y and a class X, both of which inherit QDialog. A function in class Y ( a slot), is responsible for spawning objects of class X. The dialog for Y is to be made responsible for the X objects spawned. This is why I created a QSet< X* > member in Y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot overload `operator==` like this:

```
bool operator==(X*, X*);
```

This is because at least one of the argument must be of class type.

Since you say you implemented `operator==`, I suppose you did something like this:

```
struct X
{
    bool operator==(X*) const;
};
```

This operator will never be called when `QSet` tries to fiend duplicates because it needs a left argument of type `X` and a right of type `X*`

I can see two possible solutions to this problem:

- Do not store your items as pointers (ie using `QSet<X>`). This will allow you to overload the correct operators. This solution, however, is not always feasible.
- If you could enforce somehow that there is only one object with a given id, you could just store pointers in you `QSet` without needing to overload any operators nor the `qHash` function.

**Edit**: If your design allows to create multiple `X`-objects with the same id but you only want one such object to exist at any time, maybe it's best to use a `QMap` which maps from id to `X*`. When you create a new object, do something like this:

```
QString newId = ...;
delete objectsMap[newId];
objectsMap[newId] = new X(newId);
```

---

Comment: Any idea regarding the implementation of QSet<>::contains() ?? I mean how does it check if the requested item is in the set?

Comment: In your case (using `QSet<X*>`), it will first calculate the hash value (using `qHash(X*)`). Then it will compare all entries having this hash value using the language defined `bool operator==(const X*, const X*)`.

Comment: I have tried debugging it, but none of the functions get called. Why does that happen? I'm going bananas !!

Comment: Ok I tried it myself. If you define `qHash(X*)` it definitely gets called. If you don't, it will call `template<class T> uint qHash(const T&)` which in turn calls `qHash(uint)`. About `operator==`, like I said before, you cannot overload this one. If you want to see it get called, create a `QSet<X>` and implement `X::operator==`.

Comment: I don't know how, but now the qHash is being called, but still as the operator==() is not being called, I'm helpless!! :( :(

Comment: `struct Foo{bool operator==(const Foo&) const {return true;}}; QSet<Foo> set; set << Foo(); set.contains(Foo());` In this example, the operator will definitely get called.

Comment: @Job: I have edited the question. Please check it. You might be able to help me better.

Comment: Regarding the edited post:
Looks like that's the only feasible solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact requirements, you could use a sorted vector together with std::unique (which accepts a custom binary predicate for comparison).

Comment: This would be my last choice. It would be good if I could get the QSet<>::contains() function to work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use QMap instead? Your dialog would have member variable `QMap<QString, X*> items`. Then the checking and creating new X's would be like:

```
QString name = "foo";
if (!items.contains(name))
{
    items[name] = new X(name);
}
else
{
    // "foo" already exists
}
```

Maybe this is not as elegant solution as using QSet might be, but I think this is shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, I just implemented that only!

Answer (score -1):

I get exactly the same problem. In the end I get here. My solution is very simple.
If class QSet can't do what I want, why don't use it object in my class with added code to every function I need. Here is my solution:

Declaration of Set class:

```
#pragma once
#include<Plant.h>
#include<qset.h>
class Set
{
public:
    Set(void);
    ~Set(void);
    bool contains(Plant *plant);
    QSet<Plant*>::iterator insert(Plant *plant);
    QSet<Plant*>::iterator erase(Plant *plant);
private:
    QSet<Plant*> plants;

};
```

Definition of Set class

```
#include "Set.h"


Set::Set(void){
    plants = QSet<Plant*>();
}


Set::~Set(void){
}

bool Set::contains(Plant *plant){
    for(int i=0;i<plants.size();++i){
        if(plants.values().at(i)->compare(plant))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

QSet<Plant*>::iterator Set::insert(Plant *plant){
    if(!contains(plant))
        return plants.insert(plant);
}

QSet<Plant*>::iterator Set::erase(Plant *plant){
    QSet<Plant*>::iterator it;
    for(it = plants.begin();it!=plants.end();++it){
        if((*it)->compare(plant)){
            return plants.erase(it);
        }
    }
    return it;
```

It worked for me very well.

Comment: Man, this is basically killing every advantage QSet gives you. Why not create a simple list?